# postgresql to fetch records with different column values by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

table user

```
(user_id, vehical_type, created_date)
 1        10            2020-06-01
 2        11            2019-09-09
 1        9             2020-06-02
 1        2             2020-02-01
 2        10            2019-09-06
 2         9            2019-09-11

Result
(user_id, vehical_type, created_date)
 1        10            2020-06-01
 1         9            2020-06-02
```

Query to fetch a particular users records with vehical_type 10,9 if vehicle_type 10 is followed by vehicle_type 2 by created_date

In the above result you shouldn't see user_id 2 because its vehicle_type 11(created: 2019-09-09) exists between its vehicle_type 10(2019-09-06) and 9(2019-09-11)

Comment: What would be the result for this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want `lead()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lead(vehical_type) over(partition by user_id order by created_date) lead_vehical_type
    from mytable t
) t
where vehical_type in (9, 10) and lead_vehical_type = 2
```

This brings records with `vehical_type` 9 or 10, and and whose next `vehical_type` for the same `user_id` is 2.